# magento sites are broken after updating phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, magento, phpmyadmin

I need help to resolve my problem.

Suddenly my magento sites are broken, all pages, not only front pages but also backend pages,  redirect install page, http://hogehoge.com/index.php/install/.

I don't know why this kind of problem happen.

Of course I checked server logs, my server is attacked or not but I cannot find attacked logs.

But I find one supposed reason, I think after updating phpMyAdmin my magento sites are broken.

On my server, not only magento but also another application, wordpress, piwik and so on, work but only magento had problem.

If all applications were broken, I could understand, but only magento broken I want to know what wrong is.

Maybe if I can repair by magento-db-repair tool, it's ok but I think I can't make solution basically.

So please advise me what I should check my server configuration.

My server spec is
Centos6.4 64bit
apache2.2.15
php5.4.23
mysql5.5.35
phpMyAdmin4.1.1(<=update from 4.1.0)
magento1.7.0.2 and 1.8.1.0

Thank you.

Comment: at a guess check changes to .httacess

Comment: as Dagon said, check .httaccess, also, do you have a backup from before you updated phpmyadmin?

Comment: Dear Dagon and salty , .htaccess is no problem. I just use magento default htaccess. And in this time I have no backup because Magento1.7.0.2 just prepare to open from next year and magento1.8.1.0 is for test site.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you're looking in the wrong direction. Upgrading phpMyAdmin by itself shouldn't have any effect on anything else running on the server. It's just a collection of scripts that allow you to interact with a MySQL database; there isn't anything that would affect your other site. How did you perform the phpMyAdmin upgrade? Any hints in the error log about what's going on?

Comment: Now I'm very confused. I cannot find any reason this trouble, so I tried to install new magento. But after installation finished, same things occurred! After finishing installation and clicked frontend and backend link, I cannot access both pages, just redirected Installation Wizard page, http://hogehoge.com/index.php/install/. I don't understand any reason why this kind of thing happened. If you know, please advise me.